# How to convert json array to object then chartjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, chart.js

```
function grab() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.getJSON({
      url: "/hash_results_page/",
      cache: false,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function (data) {
        resolve(data);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        reject(error);
      },
    });
  });
}
/*DATA_SAMPLE AS FROM JSON = {
                  data: [
                    { x: '2017-01-06 18:39:30', y: 100 },
                    { x: '2017-01-07 18:39:28', y: 101 },
                  ] //just like mine, but mine doesnt have  x: and y;
                };

["2022-12-11 16:45:00",0.491],["2022-12-11 17:00:00",0.464]
    "date     time",    hashvalue

*/
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function (data) {
  grab().then((data) => {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("hashchart").getContext("2d");

    var d1 = data[0];
    var d2 = data[1];
    console.log("Hashrate Data-0:", d1);
    console.log("Average Data-1:", d2);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
              /*let text = "";
                d1.forEach (function(value) { // lists all entries
                text += value;
                });
                console.log(text);*/

    //var da = JSON.stringify(data[0]); // json array into object - (other way(s) I've tried
    //obj = Object.assign({}, d1);
    //console.log(obj);

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var dat = [d1];
    var str = JSON.stringify(dat);
    var out = str.substring(1, str.length - 1);
    JSON.parse(out); //necessary???
    for (var i = 0; i < d1.length; i++) {
      console.log(d1[i++])      
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V0tF.jpg

2nd EDIT:https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZITR.jpg this is where im at now... ;(

***i really dont know where to go or what to do from here ;( i've spent so much time on this something that should been simple, and turned out to put me through the ringer!!!!***

also im wanting to show pictures, cause really dont want anyone thinking im just a code bum and wanting others to do this for me...
im actually trying to figure this out... although making progress.. but still not there yet!!!

`EDIT: picture included above of my progress thus far..
i think what i need is a for loop to iterate through the array->object data results but.. i guess that's the reason im here asking for help... thanks!

what i am trying to do is.. get json results from my api to put onto chartjs
i've searched and tried many many things from here, but my skills obviously are limited..
ive shown some of the things ive tried.. here that are commented.. and the uncommented are what i am using currently (i just hope im asking in correct place)

currently the code logs (to show) 2 arrays to start... in which, when are opened they show values like are shown above and im trying to seperate or sort to where date/time ofcourse.. is on x axis and the hash values on y axis..... ive used other charting softwares like apexcharts.. but to get it to chart correctly is nothing like this.. and i have apexcharts working at the moment but i like chartjs a bit more.. due to challening myself and flexability.. i just need to get data from the api sorted out.. i hope ive explained good enough and thoroughly to everyones understanding of what i am trying to do here... any help would be much appreciated!!!`

tried several options of js code from s.o.
and anything of my own knowledge and researched for many
many hours..

Answer (score 0):

```
var org = [["2022-12-11 16:45:00",0.491],["2022-12-11 17:00:00",0.464]];

var data = org.map(v=>{
  return {x:v[0],y:v[1]}
})
console.log(data)
```

Comment: aww, man thanks! thanks for the example. i put the correct vars in from the api for org, and it comes out showing correctly of what i been trying to do.. now i have to make it plot x & y .. i should be able to do that part.. oh  man, i been trying for loops.. for in.. an everything else.. and all i needed was object map... jeesh!! it's always the simplest things that mess you up

Comment: also i've read other people having issue when doing somthing like this.. with chartjs only plotting 2 data points... that what mine does as well.. even before finding out i needed to use map function.. except now.. its actually plotting the correct points.. but only i guess the start and end points though, i can't find where i was reading about it tho.. or if it had a fix..